# Cannot initialize observable array with data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I'm new to knockout and I have a bit of a problem with it. I have ASP.Net MVC 4 application, razor view and knockout ViewModel. I use web api controller to get data and I cannot initialize ko.observableArray with it.

**Controller function to get data:**

```
public IEnumerable<TaskModel> GetTasks()
{
    var tasks = new[] { new TaskModel { Name = "asd", Deadline = DateTime.Now, Id = new Guid() }, new TaskModel { Name = "asdfasdf", Deadline = DateTime.Now, Id = new Guid() } };
    return tasks;
}
```

**Knockout view model**(call to controller is correct, data variable is not null)

```
function TasksList() {
    var self = this;

    self.tasks = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.load = function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:11701/api/TaskApi",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                self.tasks(data);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert(error.status + "<--and--> " + error.statusText);
            }
        });
    };
}

var tasksList = new TasksList();
tasksList.load();
ko.applyBindings(tasksList);
```

**View**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/knockout-2.2.1.debug.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.debug.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Models/TasksList.js")

<h2>Tasks</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name
        </th>
        <th>Priority
        </th>
        <th>Deadline
        </th>
        <th>CreatedOn
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    <tbody data-bind="foreach: tasks" >
        <tr>            
            <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Priority"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Deadline"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: CreatedOn"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried ko.mapping.fromJS and ko.mapping.fromJSON and it still don;t work, any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? Are you getting errors thrown by the javascript? What does the data look like in your success function?

Comment: I agree with Paul Manzotti that providing some more debug info would help you get an answer here.

Comment: After calling self.tasks(data); self.tasks was still empty, despite data variable actually contains data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion your problem is that you have `ko.applyBindings` before your HTML. Invoke that code after page load:

```
$(function() {
    var tasksList = new TasksList();
    tasksList.load();
    ko.applyBindings(tasksList);
});
```

or at least move your javascript code to end of the body